# How can I add an image to a variable in whatsapp API?

Tags: php, json, api, facebook, whatsapp

Hi I am trying to send an image with Whatsapp api, I did my template like this one:

```
Hola *{{1}}* ‍♀️‍♂️

Hemos cargado una nueva noticia en la intranet, si quieres visualizar la misma haz click en el 
siguiente enlace: {{2}}

 *Jis Parking*
```

and my code is this one:

```
{
"to": "xxxxx",
"recipient_type": "individual",
"type": "template",
"template": {
    "namespace": "88b39973_f0d5_54e1_29cf_e80f1e3da4f2",
    "name": "noticia",
    "language": {
        "code": "es"
    },
    "components": [
        {
            "type": "body",
            "parameters": [
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "Richard"
                },
                {
                    "type": "image",
                    "image": {
                        "link": "image_url"
                    }
                }
            ] 
        }
    ]
   }
 }
```

I added the image_url and it's weird because I see all good and the api displays this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) The parameter messaging_product is required.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "AxtiGLSBvAZltlMkJAw-GIk"
  }
}
```

I wonder what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: you need to add the parameter "messaging_product" : "whatsapp" in your code

Answer (score 0):

Hey did you upload the image first?

To get an `id` or a `link` first you need to upload the media using the API which would return a media object with `ID` and a `link`.

I use the [Whatsapp Ruby SDK](https://github.com/ignacio-chiazzo/ruby_whatsapp_sdk) for connecting with the API which looks like this:

```rb
uploaded_media = medias_api.upload(sender_id: SENDER_ID, file_path: "tmp/whatsapp.png", type: "image/png")
media = medias_api.media(media_id: uploaded_media.data&.id).data
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the current error says you need to add the below parameter in your request,

```
"messaging_product" : "whatsapp"
```

---

Second, I notice in your request, that the `image` type is not supported in `body` type component, the body type supports these 3 types of values `text`, `currency`, `date_time`, for more details review the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/guides/send-message-templates#text-based),

If you want to add an image to your message, you have to create a new template with a `header` type as `image`, for ex:

[image]

After that, you can add an image to the `header` component, for more details review the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/guides/send-message-templates#media-based).